# gets() function gets skipped from the second time onwards

Tags: c, goto, gets

I was playing with C and wrote this code:

```
   1 #include<stdio.h>
   2 #define ASK_PROMPT printf("\nDo you want to continue(Y/N):");
   3 main()
   4 {
   5    char main[20], i;
   6    start:
   7    printf("Please enter your string:\n");
   8    gets(main);
   9    printf("\nstring entered was:\n \n%s\n", main);
   10   ASK_PROMPT;
   11   scanf("%c",&i);
   12       
   13   if(i=='Y'||i=='y')
   14       goto start;
   15   getch();
   16   return;
   17 }
```

when I execute this code, the `goto loop` is not working correctly. On providing `y` or `Y` response to question asked from line 10, loop does work and line 7 is again executed/printed but line 8 was skipped(doesn't wait for the input to be provided).

- Can anyone explain why it is happening?
- How do I fix it?

Comment: This code should the classic example of what **not** to do.

Comment: It's almost as you hit more than one key in order to enter `'Y'` or `'y'`. But that would be pretty obvious, so you must have already excluded that possibility in your debugging...

Comment: means, goto should not be used? I generally don't use goto. but what I want to ask is why its not requesting for input. Does program forget that main is declared already? (please don't mind "main" as that another thing I was trying)

Comment: see if your problem is not similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c (simplified: input stream needing to be flushed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Fix

Change `scanf("%c",&i);` to `scanf("%c%*c",&i);`.

## Problem

The `\n` after inputting `i` is what is causing `gets()` not to wait for input.

## Good practices

- **Stop** using `gets()`, `goto` etc. Instead, you can use `fgets()`, `scanf()` etc. Never use deprecated functions.
- Change `char` array name from `main` to something else, say `m`.

Thanks @Coolguy for the comment on use of scanf.

Comment: Thanks for replying and advice, but even after the changing the code as per your suggestion it is showing the same problem

Comment: I have tried it on my system and then posted the answer. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @user2507780 Use `scanf("%c%*c", &i);`. I would suggest using @ameyCU's solution though

Comment: I have dev-cpp installed(mingw64 gcc is its part of package) and using its compiler for c (after saving into .c extension) Am I doing this wrong as well?

Comment: I used to use dev-cpp around 4 yrs ago. Used it for sometime but left because it had a very different behavior than standard gcc compiler that linux uses. It does not give exact warnings or exit status (segfault etc) if code crashes, so its really hard to debug.

Comment: @CoolGuy, thanks for the correct formatting of scanf. Can you explain the difference in behavior of scanf when we use `"%c%\n"` or when we use `"%c%*c"`

Comment: Thank you @vish4071,as per the suggestion of "coolguy" from comments, code is now good. thank you for your time and help. have a nice day

Comment: @vish4071 Sure. Here `"%c%\n"`, `\n` is a whitespace character. And when there is a whitespace character in the format string of `scanf`, it will scan and discard whitespace characters, if any, **until the first non-whitespace character**. On the other hand, `%*c` simply scans and discards a character.

Comment: thanks @CoolGuy. When I did not know how to scan multiple words with scanf, I used gets() even when I did not want to and have faced similar problems. I found this solution to scan newline myself and it did rectify for many usecases and somehow worked. If I knew or could think of scanning a char * instead, it'd have been great. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not required. Its better formatting now. Thanks for the edit as well :)

Comment: `scanf("%c%*c",&i);` scans _any_ 2 characters.  `scanf("%c%*1[\n]",&i);`, as ugly as it is, scans one character and then a potential following `'\n'`.  IAC better to go with [`fgets()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32502901/2410359)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **not** to use `gets`.While using `gets` what if string entered is larger than the size of `main[20]` .`gets` won't prevent this and it will cause **UB**.

Use `fgets`-

```
fgets(main,20,stdin);
```

And reason for your problem is that `'\n'` after the `scanf("%c",&i);` which remains in `stdin` causes this as `gets` return as it encounter `'\n'`.

To avoid `'\n'` you can do this after `scanf` statement -

```
int c;
while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n' );
```

Comment: Thank you for replying, I make the changes as per your suggestion. after the changes the first letter of string was deleted/truncated and the problem remain as such.

Comment: @user2507780  You added the code as I said ? The line with `getchar` should be after `scanf("%c",&i);` in your code.

Comment: @CoolGuy  Ahh I always forget that it adds null . Thank You !! :)

Comment: even then, its not working, but as per @coolguy suggestion I used scanf("%c%*c", &i);  and now its working fine. Thanks for you time and help. Have a nice day.

Comment: @user2507780  Well I don't understand how it didn't work for you as it worked perfectly. Never mind  cheers !!

Comment: I don't why yesterday it was not working, but today it works.. Thanks @ameyCU

Answer (score 1):

**The problem:**

After typing <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> in response to your prompt, the input stream for your program contains the characters `'y'` and `'\n'` (the newline character).  The `scanf` call removes the `'y'` character from the input stream, leaving the newline character in place.

`gets` reads from the input stream until it sees a newline character, which it discards; since the first thing it sees is the newline character from the previous entry, it returns without reading any further input.

**The solution:**

First, don't use `gets`.  Ever.  It was deprecated in the 1999 revision and has been removed completely from the 2011 revision.  Using it *will* introduce a point of failure/security hole in your program.  Replace that with a call to `fgets` instead, just be aware that `fgets` will try to store the newline in the target buffer if there's room.

Second, you need to consume that trailing newline from the input stream.  The answer given by vish4071 shows one approach - use `scanf` to read the character following your input (which should be the newline) and discard it:

```
scanf( " %c%*c", &i );
```

The leading blank in the format string tells `scanf` to skip any leading whitespace, the `%c` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to read the next character from the input stream and store its value into `i`, and the `%*c` conversion specifier tells `scanf` to read the next character from the input stream and discard it.

Another option is to consume input until you see a newline:

```
scanf( " %c", &i );
while ( getchar() != '\n' )  // repeatedly read characters from input stream
  ;                          // until we see a newline
```

Yet another option is to read your input as another string:

```
char answer[3]; // space for y/n response plus newline plus 0 terminator
...
if ( fgets( answer, sizeof answer, stdin ) )
{
  if ( tolower( answer[0] ) == 'y' )
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

You will probably want to check for the presence of the newline character in the `answer` buffer; if it isn't there, then the user typed in more characters than your buffer was sized to hold, which will likely foul up a future read, and you need to clear that spurious input before your next read operation:

```
if ( !strchr( answer, '\n' ) )
  while ( getchar() != '\n' )
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Minimal fix to existing code, just use gets(main) a second time. If the code is going to use ASK_PROMPT;, then the define for ASK_PROMPT doesn't need a trailing ; . As already suggested, you can use fgets() instead of gets(), and use a proper loop instead of start: and goto.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define ASK_PROMPT printf("\nDo you want to continue(Y/N):")
int main()
{
    char main[20];
    start:
    printf("Please enter your string:\n");
    gets(main);
    printf("\nstring entered was:\n \n%s\n", main);
    ASK_PROMPT;
    gets(main);
    if(main[0]=='Y'||main[0]=='y')
        goto start;
    getch();
    return(0);
}
```